# How to dynamically add menu items to a popup?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I need to implement a header with a dropdown menu. There are three menu items in the header and the fourth item is the ellipsis. When hovering on the ellipsis, the menu drops out. How can I implement such a functionality - when adding a new menu item, the last 3rd item is added to the popup menu, and there will be a new item in 1st place. Right now in my code I dynamically add 3 dots if there are more than 3 items. How can I add menu items to the popup?

```js
// ===== ADAPTIVE MENU

const headerMenu = document.querySelector(".header-menu__list");
const headerMenuLi = document.querySelectorAll(".header-menu__list li");
const headerMenuToArray = Array.from(headerMenuLi);
const ellipsisLi = document.createElement("li");
ellipsisLi.classList.add("open-sub__menu");
const ellipsisA = document.createElement("a");
ellipsisA.innerHTML = "<span>...</span>";
const subMenu = document.createElement("ul");
subMenu.classList.add("header-sub__menu");
ellipsisLi.appendChild(ellipsisA);
ellipsisLi.appendChild(subMenu);

const addEllipsis = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length > 3) {
    headerMenu.children[2].after(ellipsisLi);
  }
};

addEllipsis(headerMenuToArray);
```

```css
.header-sub__menu {
  background: #171a21 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.open-sub__menu:hover .header-sub__menu {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-menu">
  <ul class="header-menu__list">
    <li><a href="">Find events</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Create an event</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: use an array to hold the items. utilize arr[0] - arr[2] for the menu and arr[3+] for rest. once a new item arrives. reverse your array, push the item, reverse back.
reverse: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse
splice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Can you look at my code and please tell me how I can add menu items that the user adds in HTML to the popup. So that the old ones go to the popup, and the new ones are in their place

Answer (score 0):

This "solution" isnt production ready at all. but you're able to spot how to manipulate the DOM.

HTML

```html
<ul id="nav"></ul>
```

JavaScript

```js
const navElement = document.querySelector('#nav');

const navigationItems = ['Home', 'About', 'Products', 'Support', 'Contact'];

const createListItem = (label) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = label;
    return li;
};


let i = 0;
for (i; i < 3; i++) {
    navElement.appendChild(createListItem(navigationItems[i]));
}

const ellipsisListItemElement = document.createElement('li');
ellipsisListItemElement.innerText = '...';

const subNav = document.createElement('ul');
ellipsisListItemElement.appendChild(subNav);

for (i; i < navigationItems.length; i++) {
    subNav.appendChild(createListItem(navigationItems[i]));
}

navElement.appendChild(ellipsisListItemElement);
```

DONT use this code. create your own and clean solution